# How to exchange two patterns in place with `sed`?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell-script, sed, xml

I am using `sed` command to change `<active>true` to `<active>false` in an xml file. Now if I use

```
sed 's/<active>true/<active>false/g' file.xml > file.xml
```

it completely erases the content of my file. While using `>>` instead of `>`, it appends output at the end like it is expected to do.

1. How to achieve what I want to do?
2. Why is `>` behaving so weirdly?
3. What i actually want to do is change `<active>true` to `<active>false` if `<active>true` is present and vice versa if `<active>false` is present in file. Is there some command that can do it or do I need to write a script with `if-else` like my original plan?

Comment: 2: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79039/108618). Investigate `sed -i`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski so in short `file.xml` was truncated before `sed` was executed?

Comment: Yes. In Linux there is a general tool to avoid this: [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge).

Comment: thanks, `sed -i` solved ques 2 and 1, though on using sponge, it gave `command not found` error

Comment: In Debian or Ubuntu `sponge` is a part of `moreutils` package which is not installed by default. I guess in other distros the situation is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `>` is explained in [this Unix & Linux SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79039/108618). The example there is `cat test.txt > test.txt` and the explanation is:

> The first thing that happens is bash opens `test.txt`, which truncates the file. It is now empty, before `cat` is executed with `test.txt` as an argument.

Your `sed '…' file.xml > file.xml` triggers the same behavior.

Quite straightforward solution with a single `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/<active>true/<active>DUMMY/g
   s/<active>false/<active>true/g
   s/<active>DUMMY/<active>false/g' file.xml
```

The `-i` option solves your problem with the file being truncated. The command turns `<active>true` into `<active>false` and vice versa. Note you cannot use just

```
s/<active>true/<active>false/g;s/<active>false/<active>true/g
```

because the second part cannot tell if any `false` is the original `false` or the original `true` just turned into `false`. This causes every matching `true` or `false` end up as `true`. For this reason I used the temporary `DUMMY` replacement. Maybe there is a better way to do it, I don't know it yet.

The only condition is the string `<active>DUMMY` cannot appear in the original file. If it may appear, use another dummy string which doesn't appear for sure.