# How to output a particular word in file, if it is present?

Tags: bash, shell, regex, shell-script, grep

I am making a simple script where i turn `true` to `false` if `true` is present in file or vice versa if `false` is present in file, details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1344547/how-to-exchange-two-patterns-in-place-with-sed#1344563). Now i want to output, what is the value after change ie if i changed `false` to `true` it should output `true`. Right now i am using two statements -

`grep "<active>false" settings.xml`

`grep "<active>true" settings.xml`

But it prints `<active>` with the output(as expected), but is there a better way to do this?

Side Note - I am using `<active>true` in `grep` because my regex is of type `<active>([a-z]*)</active>`

Comment: Remove the excess by filtering the output with sed: `grep "<active>false" settings.xml | sed -e 's/<active>//'`

Comment: Is it an XML file?

Comment: yes it is xml file

Comment: In this case you should use any XML-tool because sed/grep/.. are line-oriented - for example xmllint, xmlstarlet (http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html or http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). Who guarantees that the `<active>` and `true` are in same line?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU `grep`, you can use [Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) with a positive lookbehind assertion:

```
grep -Po "(?<=<active>)(false|true)" settings.xml
```

This will output only `false` or `true`. `<active>` will be matched, when it is followed by `true` or `false`, but it will not included in the output.

But ideally you should use an XML-based parser as suggested in [the comment by uzsolt](https://superuser.com/questions/1344688/how-to-output-a-particular-word-in-file-if-it-is-present#comment2013730_1344688).